# Array following a curve - Simple Deform (Bend) modifier ignored?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have the feeling I am doing something really wrong, but I do not get it:

I am using a curve to define the shape of a circular wall. Then I paint small cubes along that curve with the array and curve modifiers to create the circular wall. This works nicely. I need the curve, because I am using geometry nodes to place additional objects along that wall, which need to face the wall. This also works.

Now I tried to change the shape of my curve, which is a bezier circle with the simple deform bend modifier along the Z axis. The preview of the curve reflects the shape change from the modifier, but my wall is drawn along the unmodified curve. It seems to me that the curve modifier that I apply to the cube discards the simple deform?

Also, when I try to apply the simple deform to the curve, the modifier is removed but the curve shape reverts to the original, unmodified shape. Why is this happening? :)

[image]

[Edit: I have added a blender file that illustrates the problem]

[image]

Comment: Could you show at least the modifier settings on the cube as well? Because I cannot reproduce what you are describing here. In my Blender, changing the shape of the curve is taken into account by the _Array_ modifier on the cube and applying the _Simple Deform_ on the curve also applies the changes to the curve. Are you **applying** the modifier with Ctrl+A or choosing _Apply_ from the modifier menu or **removing** it by just pressing the X on the menu? Maybe it helps if you upload your file here https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Comment: Thank you! I have added a minimal blender file that illustrates my problem. I apply the modifier from the drop down menu right beside the x button. The message "applied modifier only changed CV points, not tesselated/bevel vertices" appears when I apply the modifier. I did not notice that message before tbh.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the technicalities behind this, but I'm pretty sure the when you put a modifier on a curve (e.g. SimpleDeform, Mirror, SubSurf etc.) it's actually acting on the Mesh representation of the curve object, kind of playing both sides of the fence, so to speak. So applying modifiers will have no effect if you stay in the "Curve object domain". You would need to Convert > To Mesh, and then back to Curve in order to get the exact effect you want.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Well, but I had a _Simple Deform_ modifier with his settings on a curve circle and applied the modifier, and the appearance stayed the same although the deformed circle was still a curve object. And changing the shape of the circle didn't lead to the _Array_ modifier now using the unmodified circle instead. However, the screenshot clearly shows the circle is an oval, so there's probably some unapplied scale on it which can always create problems. Unfortunately I'm not on a PC anymore so I can't check his file.

Comment: I did in fact scale the curve to resemble an oval, could that cause the problem?

Comment: @Thomas The scaling itself not necessarily, but if you did it in _Object Mode_ without applying it afterwards, this can cause problems or at least weird behaviour with all kinds of operations and modifiers in Blender. For example if a cube has a scale of 1 on XY and 2 on Z, a _Bevel_ modifier set to a bevel amount of 0.1 m will create a bevel of 0.1 in XY direction, but 0.2 m in Z direction.